# Postgresql двойной "SELECT" и "JOIN"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

```
SELECT j_nar.id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, date_start_production,
j_catalog_vrach.fam , left(j_catalog_vrach.name, 1), left(j_catalog_vrach.lastname, 1)
FROM j_nar 
LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach ON j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped = j_catalog_vrach.id 
WHERE j_nar.id_patient = 71
UNION
SELECT j_nar.id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, date_start_production,
j_catalog_vrach.fam , left(j_catalog_vrach.name, 1), left(j_catalog_vrach.lastname, 1)
FROM j_nar
LEFT JOIN j_nar ON j_nar.id_vrach_technic = j_catalog_vrach.id 
WHERE j_nar.id_patient = 71
```

Не работает,

подскажите как правильно сформировать подобный запрос.

привел запрос к такому виду:

```
SELECT distinct j_nar.id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, date_start_production,
j_catalog_vrach.fam , left(j_catalog_vrach.name, 1), left(j_catalog_vrach.lastname, 1)
FROM j_nar 
LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach ON j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped = j_catalog_vrach.id 
WHERE j_nar.id_patient = 71
UNION
SELECT distinct j_nar.id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, date_start_production,
j_catalog_vrach.fam , left(j_catalog_vrach.name, 1), left(j_catalog_vrach.lastname, 1)
FROM j_nar 
LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach ON j_nar.id_vrach_technic = j_nar.id_vrach_technic
WHERE j_nar.id_patient = 71
```

теперь все отрабатывает, но получается он дублирует записи, а нужно выставлять в одной "строке"

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Выдаёт не те результаты? Какие ожидались, какие выдаёт?

Comment: Попробуй UNION ALL вместо UNION.

Comment: При использовании UNION записи не могут дублироваться. А если Вы понимаете под "дублирует записи" совпадение значений только части полей - то это нормально, потому как дубликатом являются только записи, совпадающие по значениям всех полей. Кстати, при использовании UNION дополнительный DISTINCT в частных запросах вряд ли имеет смысл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вот-так:

```
SELECT
j_nar.date_open_nar, j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped, j_catalog_vrach.fam as fam_vrach, j_nar.id_vrach_technic, j_catalog_vrach_1.fam as fam_technic
FROM 
(j_nar INNER JOIN j_catalog_vrach ON j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped = j_catalog_vrach.id)
INNER JOIN j_catalog_vrach AS j_catalog_vrach_1 ON j_nar.id_vrach_technic = j_catalog_vrach_1.id
```